# PR2 Velocity Control

Tags: ros, velocity, pr2, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to control the velocity (effort) of a PR2's gripper? So instead giving the position of the gripper, calculating the IK etcetc, I would like to give the velocity of the gripper as a vector and the arm will move accordingly until told otherwise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12768/pr2-velocity-control/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is CartesianTwistController in robot_mechanism_controllers which should do exactly what you want. I don't know if there is a working configuration/launch file for PR2 though. But I think it shouldn't be too hard to configure.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2012-01-26**:
Great, I knew it was somewhere. I'll try it, many thanks